# Findall() is not finding all the numbers in a text file

Tags: python, numbers

The code is supposed to find 90 numbers with a sum of 445833.
My code is finding 89 numbers with a sum of 445829. What am I doing wrong?

```
fn=open('regex_sum_42.txt','r')

import re
numbers = []
count = 0

for line in fn:
    line = line.split()
    for char in line:
        n=re.findall('[0-9]+',char)
        if len(n)>0:
            count += 1
            for num in n:
                num = int(num)
            numbers.append(num)
print(sum(numbers))
print(count)
```

Text file: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out you have some indentation errors but the overall approach can be simplified a bit.

- You don't need `count` as `len(numbers)` would give you the same answer.
- You can use `re.findall()` on the whole line not just a `word`.
- You don't need the condition as `for` will exit if there are no `n`s.

E.g.:

```
for line in fn:
    n = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for num in n:
        num = int(num)
        numbers.append(num)
print(sum(numbers))
print(len(numbers))

Out[]:
445833
90
```

You can also use `list.extend()` to replace the inner `for`-loop, leading to:

```
In []:
import re

numbers = []

with open('regex_sum_42.txt', 'r') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        numbers.extend(int(num) for num in re.findall('[0-9]+', line))

print(sum(numbers))
print(len(numbers))

Out[]:
445833
90
```

Comment: Surely if you are using `re.findall` you should use it on the whole file, not just one line at a time? This would simplify the code and removes unnecessary steps.

Comment: @TheOtterlord You can do but you increase the memory usage.

Comment: Yes, you could use it on the whole file, but it means loading the whole file into memory, which could be a challenge. This iterates over the file line at a time. Depends on the constraints.

Comment: Good point. Especially when working with bigger files

Answer (score 1):

Two things:-

1. The count update is in the wrong location, just move it down into the for loop
2. Sum is wrong because indentation for `numbers.append(num)` is not correct

Try the following code

```
fn = open('regex_sum_42.txt','r')

import re
numbers = []
count = 0

for line in fn:
    line = line.split()
    for char in line:
        n=re.findall('[0-9]+',char)
        if len(n)>0:
            for num in n:
                count += 1
                num = int(num)
                numbers.append(num)
print(sum(numbers))
print(count)
```

Comment: 1. Count should not start at 1 because nothing has yet been counted

Answer (score 1):

The `count += 1` is in the wrong place.

Move it to the inside of `for num in n:` to make it count each num.

Also move `numbers.append(num)` up to the loop. This makes sure that **all** `num` values are added instead of just the last one in a line.

```py
fn=open('text.txt','r')

import re
numbers = []
count = 0

for line in fn:
    line = line.split()
    for char in line:
        n=re.findall('[0-9]+',char)
        if len(n)>0:
            for num in n:
                count += 1
                num = int(num)
                numbers.append(num)
print(sum(numbers))
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

With simpler code, you can avoid the chance of these bugs appearing.

This code uses the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in function to iterate through all the results of [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall) and turn them into an `int` before appending them all to a list (`numbers`). You can then print the `sum` and `len` of `numbers`.

```py
with open('regex_sum_42.txt') as f:
  numbers = [*map(int, re.findall('\d+', f.read()))]
  print(sum(numbers), len(numbers))
```